# DialogFlow - change language/locale in reaction to an intent

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-es

In DialogFlow connected to a chat, I need to change language (of intents) from within an intent's action (en to fr for example)?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can set up locales for a language from the languages tab of dialogflow.

[Please refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GibfX.png)

Comment: Ershadi, that is correct. I already have the two languages configured. What I need is to switch language from within an intent. I need to do it in request from client in the middle of a discussion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) `queryInput.audioConfig.languageCode` can be defined. Basically, you can send the language with your request. You can use [one of these languages](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/language).